Is there OpenTelemetry agent that collects metrics at the process level?
Does OTel agent linked below provide a drill down of utilization metrics at the process level? If not, are there any alternatives or ongoing work in this area? We've found process level metrics extremely helpful for diagnosis of various issues. It would be beneficial to capture these metrics historically to observe usage trends for capacity planning and monitor automatically to find abnormalities at the process level.
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/receiver/hostmetricsreceiver/README.md
I came across Sysdig Agent that provides this feature but it is a propietary and a paid product, and very likely not compatible with OTel.
